# Javascript onSubmit function auto executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a problem with my validation code... I got a form with two fields (user, pass) and a jQuery function that executes a function on submit:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#login-form').on('submit', validateData());

    function validateData() {
        userInput = $('#in-user');
        userCntrl = userInput.closest('.control-group');
        passInput = $('#in-pass');
        passCntrl = passInput.closest('.control-group');

        userCntrl.addClass('error'); // This executes on page load, not on submit

        formSubmit = false;

        console.log( userInput.val() ); // This logs on page load, not on submit

        return formSubmit;
    }
});
```

The fact is that this code runs on page load but onSubmit nothing happens...

I'm sure this is an easy one, but I can't see a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need:

```
$('#login-form').on('submit', validateData);
```

Note the lack of parentheses after `validateData`.

As you have it, you're **calling** the function on page load and setting its return value (`false`) as the `submit` handler for your form.

(And you should do that *after* defining the `validateData` function.)

Comment: The function will be in a separate file, but ignoring that, why should I declare the function first?

Comment: @AxelA.Grazx: No technical reason, but a matter of style - referencing a function in the current block before you've defined it is valid JavaScript, but looks weird, and will fail if you ever change your coding style to `validateData = function () { ... }`.

Answer (score 3):

Should be:

```
$('#login-form').on('submit', validateData);
```